# Javascript - correcting form

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to correct a form but the javascript code wont stick. Does anyone know what the problem might be? I´ve tried for hours but the browser wont recognise any of the javascript code..

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/structure.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/form.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/theme.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="scripts/validate.js"></script>
</head>
```

Something is wrong with the file structure. I have the javascript file in folder "scripts" and the name of the file is "validate.js". Everything should work but it doesnt..

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    form.onsubmit = validate;

    function validate() {

      var firstName = document.getElementById("field_firstname").value;

      if (firstName.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        document.getElementById("field_firstname");
        return false;
      }

      var lastName = document.getElementById("field_lastname").value;
      if (lastName.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        document.getElementById("field_lastname");
        return false;
      }

      var email = document.getElementById("field_email").value;
      if (email.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your full e-mail adress");
        document.getElementById("field_email");
        return false;
      }

      if (confirm("Do you wish to complete the registration?")) {
        return true;
      } else {
        alert("The registration was cancelled");
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: Use <form id="registration_form" onsubmit="validate()">

Comment: Include your html - there is a typo`lastName.length == 0` within the block about the email.

Comment: is your code included in the `<head>` section?

Comment: It is included.. not even a simple "hello world" statement works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working (see included snippet).

I noticed some brace issues in your posted code. Validate and the onload function are not closed (missing  } )

It  might also be the case that onload is already fired when your script is loaded.  You might want to test if onload function is called. (debugger; console.log() or an alert ('onload');

```js
window.onload=function(){
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.onsubmit = validate;
}



function validate() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById("field_firstname").value;

    if (firstName.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        document.getElementById("field_firstname");
        return false;
    }

    var lastName = document.getElementById("field_lastname").value;
    if (lastName.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        document.getElementById("field_lastname");
        return false;
    }

    var email = document.getElementById("field_email").value;
    if (lastName.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter your full e-mail adress");
        document.getElementById("field_email");
        return false;
    }

    if (confirm("Do you wish to complete the registration?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("The registration was cancelled");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
 field_firstname<input id="field_firstname" type="text"><br/>
 field_lastname<input id="field_lastname" type="text"><br/>
 field_email<input id="field_email" type="text"><br/>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: there is a typo from the op `lastName.length == 0` within the block about the email.